# Configuring AOP with ZK to intercept methods

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop, zk

Before certain methods (or as of now all the methods) I have to call the method of an Aspect to log some  messages. My application is functioning correctly otherwise but none of the methods of the Aspect class are called.

I have tried the same cutpoint in same folder structure in my local application but when I try to include it with ZK i am having issues. I have also modified my `application-context.xml` to support AOP.

This is my aspect class :

```
package com.mypckg.services.impl;

import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.AfterReturning;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;

@Aspect
public class MyIntercpeter {

    @Pointcut("execution(* com.mypckg.services.impl.MyService.getStudents(..))")
    public void performance() {
    }

    @Before("performance()")
    public void doSomethingBeforeExecution() {
        System.out.println("Before execution method called...");


    }

    @AfterReturning("performance()")
    public void doSomethingAfterExecution() {
        System.out.println("After execution method called...");

    }
}
```

The modifications I made in the `application-context.xml` are

```
<beans  .........

    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"

    xsi:schemaLocation="
           ..........
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd">


.....

<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
<context:annotation-config />
```

Am I missing something? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you missed an obvious thing : you forgot to declare beans in spring config?

From Spring docs:

Spring AOP only supports method execution join points for Spring beans, so you can think of a pointcut as matching the execution of methods on Spring beans.

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/aop.html

You can declare your beans with annotations or by config.

Also would be better to put a version of spring you use (I supposed it was 2.0.x).

Comment: I have declared all the beans in spring configuration file. I have given only the modified part of the spring application context file. We are using Spring 2.5

Comment: Just to mention : you can use perf4j which already has annotations and annotation processor to measure performance. [http://perf4j.codehaus.org/devguide.html#Unobtrusive_Logging_with_Profiled_and_AOP](http://perf4j.codehaus.org/devguide.html#Unobtrusive_Logging_with_Profiled_and_AOP).